# Enabling the new Gmail 'tabbed view' on Google Apps for Business Gmail accounts

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I really like the new [Gmail tabbed view](http://lifehacker.com/gmail-gets-a-new-tabbed-view-so-you-can-see-whats-new-510289997) layout and use it on my personal Gmail account, but when looking at my work Google Apps for Business accounts I can't see how to enable it. Any ideas?

I'm also the Google Apps admin so I can make any changes in the control panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your users should be able to have it, since it was released in general on the 5th. ([source](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2013/06/scheduled-release-updates-for-june-5th.html))

Here is what I had to do:

1. Hold your mouse over "Inbox" on the left side of the window
2. Click the down arrow that appears.
3. Mouse over "Default"
4. Click "Manage your inbox settings"
5. Check the appropriate tabs that you want, and click Save

Comment: This didn't work for me on my Google Apps BUSINESS (custom domain) account, all of the tabs are greyed out and I can't click them. Works on my personal account though